# R shiny gvisTable with columns selected by user in defined order

Tags: r, shiny

I have an [R shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) webpage where I currently use [`gvisTable`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/googleVis/docs/gvisTable) to show a selection of columns from a data.frame. The rows are dynamically selected by the user with the `sidebarPanel`, but right now the columns are hard-coded inside the `gvisTable` call.

I would like to allow the user to dynamically select the columns from a drop-down menu (see snapshot of a similar system from a non-shiny webpage). The key feature I want is to allow resorting of the columns.

[image]

Any ideas how to pass this sorted selection of columns in shiny?

I don't mind using something else instead of `gvisTable` if it does the job.

EDIT: Thanks for showing a solution using the sortable answer. It works both for my old and new versions of shiny. Yet, this does not seem to remember the order upon hitting "Refresh", which would be really nice to have.

So, can it save the last chosen order as a browser cookie or a similar way? The server is authenticated, and I've been told I could put the variable order in a list with the user id as the key. An example of that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Shiny you would have to use multiple selectInput's. However, you could install ShinySky by ZJ (https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky) and use his select2 binding which allows sorting. Alternatively, you could modify the sortable binding at https://github.com/mostly-harmless/sortable.

Edit: I don't know about cookies. I use sortable in a larger [app](http://vnijs.rady.ucsd.edu:3838/marketing/). There I have an action button to save the order selected by the user. See Data > Transform > Reorder columns. In the app data is stored in a reactiveValue. To save the data order I use `values[[input$datasets]] <- values[[input$datasets]][,input$tr_reorder_cols]` where `input$datasets` is the active dataset, `input$tr_reorder_cols` is the users selected variable ordering, and `values` is the reactiveValue that contains the data.

The source for the app is on Github: https://github.com/mostly-harmless/radiant

As an alternative, you could also save the order of the variables in a reactiveValue. See the [Shiny](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/reactiveValues) documentation for details.

Edit:

In global.R define a reactiveValue:

```
savedOrder <- reactiveValues()
```

When a user changes the order (this assumes you have userid available as a variable in R):

```
if(!is.null(input$sortable)) {
    savedOrder[[userid]] <- input$sortable
}
```

Also, you could pass the id-value to returnOrder in case of a refresh:

```
if(!is.null(savedOrder[[userid]])) {
    returnOrder("sortable",savedOrder[[userid]])
} else {
    returnOrder("sortable",colnames(dat))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I tried it on two servers, the production server which is an old shiny 0.4.0 and a 0.8.0 server on my VM. On the 0.4.0 server, I get an `Could not find function "includeCSS"`, and in the 0.8.0 I get an `Error: cannot open the connection`. Any ideas?

Comment: I gave two suggestions. What exactly did you try?

Comment: I removed the dependence on includeCSS. Try shiny::runGitHub('sortable','mostly-harmless'). As mentioned, you would need to adapt sortable for your needs. ShinySky's select2 binding might be an easier option.

Comment: this is awesome and it works both for my new server and my old server. Can it save the last chosen order as a cookie or something? Added a bounty for it.

Comment: thanks, I see how it's done in your app: every time a user changes the column order, the information is sent back to the server and changes the status of the Shiny server, making the changes permanent for every other user in every other browser. Is that so?

Comment: I designed my app to (mainly) to be run locally. values is set globally so each user, it seems, will see the same data. I think a shiny session is reset when you hit refresh so setting a global variable may be the only option. Since your app is authenticated perhaps you could put the variable order in a list with the user id as the key?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it with user ids. Any code I could use as inspiration?

Comment: I don't know what you are using for authentication. If you can access the userid from R then you can use the edits to my answer.